# Stuck installing node with Homebrew in MacOS: fork.rb:49:in `write': Broken pipe (Errno::EPIPE)

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew

I am consistently getting the error below during the `postinstall` step when installing node in macOS Sierra.

```
$ brew postinstall node --verbose
==> Postinstalling node
/usr/bin/sandbox-exec -f /private/tmp/homebrew20180915-55177-tjsmxe.sb nice /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.7/bin/ruby -W0 -I /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.0.0/lib:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin9.0:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/universal-darwin9.0:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.7/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.7/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin9.0:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.7/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0/universal-darwin9.0:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.7/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin9.0:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/universal-darwin9.0:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew -- /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/postinstall.rb /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/node.rb --verbose
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:49:in `write': Broken pipe (Errno::EPIPE)
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:49:in `puts'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:49:in `rescue in block (3 levels) in safe_fork'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:31:in `block (3 levels) in safe_fork'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:30:in `fork'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in safe_fork'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:27:in `open'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:27:in `block in safe_fork'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tmpdir.rb:89:in `mktmpdir'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:26:in `safe_fork'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:886:in `post_install'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/postinstall.rb:14:in `block in postinstall'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/postinstall.rb:11:in `each'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/postinstall.rb:11:in `postinstall'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:89:in `<main>'
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall node`
```

I have this version of Homebrew:

```
Homebrew 1.7.4
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision a216b; last commit 2018-09-15)
```

I uninstalled node but that didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ran into the same issue today. It turned out to be an issue with permissions on /usr/local.

To change ownership of /usr/local:
`sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*`

Remove broken node install: `brew uninstall node`

Re-install node: `brew install node`

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you so much, David!

Comment: This worked for me as well, thank you! I wanted to note that I started seeing this error right after running `brew upgrade npm`, in case other people run into it in that context.